# Странное использование слова инцест

Tags: значения

> — Хочешь, я буду звать тебя Кэтрин, как в старых романах. В старых романах герой всегда прощался перед путешествием и обещал привезти что-нибудь. Аленький цветочек, например.
>   
> — Аленький цветочек это уже **инцест**. Ты всё-таки не мой папа. — Она улыбнулась в темноте, но я, хоть и ничего не видел, знал, что она улыбается. К счастью.

В чём здесь дело? Я не вижу никакой связи кровосмешения с алыми цветками.

Comment: Russian word *жадный* means "greedy". There is no single word in Russian which would correspond to Polish *żaden*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Аленький цветочек" - это название сказки Аксакова. Сюжет - вариация на тему "Красавица и чудовище".

Аленький цветочек, упоминаемый в заглавии, обещал привезти девушке отец (но сорвав его, он прогневал чудовище, что и является завязкой сюжета). Отсюда в общем-то и ассоциация.

Answer (score 7):

В книге, из которой вы цитируете отрывок, герои занимались сексом, а цветок в сказке привозил папа. Отсюда и намек на инцест. :)

Comment: Для желающих убедиться самим, просто гуглим и смотрим контекст, из которого взят диалог.